# Sharepoint Check-In Document using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Does anyone know why the Set-PnPFileCheckedIn cmdlet below does nothing when executed? The file doesn't get checked in. I'm logging in with the same user that has the file checked out.

I'm not even seeing an error message. The script just runs through.

```
$SiteUrl = "https://orgsite.com/sites/TestSite"
$fileRelativePath = "/sites/TestSite/Documents/File.pdf"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -UseWebLogin
    
Set-PnPFileCheckedIn -Url $fileRelativePath
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this works for me.

Please make sure the relative url of the file is right, I assume the fileRelativePath shuold be  `"/sites/TestSite/Shared Documents/File.pdf"`.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, should Shared Documents always be referenced here? and does it apply for all documents regardless of what library its in?

Comment: For libraries in SharePoint, the title and the url  may be different. You should use the url for fileRelativePath. The Documents library has the url  "/sites/TestSite/Shared Documents". You could check that in my updated answer.